# How to establish foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I got three tables.

```
User
Project
WorkFlow
```

> In workflow ProjectId, UserId together should never repeat. Thats my
>   requirement.I mean the combination should never repeat.
>
> And the ProjectId should be present in the Project table and UserId
>   should be present in the User table.

This is the requirement.

**Steps i tried :**

I made `ProjectId, UserId` as composite key in workFlow. But cant be able to maintain foreign key since two columns are not available in single table.

How to resolve this.

I am open to change my design also, since this is the initial stage of my development.

**Main reuirement is**

> One table to store project (project table) related informations and
>   the other one(workFlow) hold the record which project is assigned to
>   which user.

Comment: You can also enforce uniqueness of non-PK columns using a UNIQUE KEY CONSTRAINT, or a UNIQUE (clustered or non clustered) INDEX?

Comment: @StuartLC So can remove the composite key and make those two columns as unique key?

Comment: Yes, like @Roger's answer below (+1), although suggest you name the UKC.

Comment: @StuartLC, I wrote it all by hands, so kept it short. In real practise, some CASE tool is usually very useful, as well as a couple of constraint-renaming scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign keys do not control uniqueness; they only control referential integrity. For uniqueness, you need unique constraints:

```
create table dbo.Workflow (
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    ProjectId int not null,
    UserId int not null,
    foreign key (ProjectId) references dbo.Project (Id),
    foreign key (UserId) references dbo.[User] (Id),
    unique (UserId, ProjectId)
);
```

**EDIT:** If you don't need a surrogate key in this table, and don't care much about its possible children, you can simplify the structure by switching from surrogate primary key to the natural one. With table becoming more narrow, it will increase performance in high load scenarios by reducing its disk footprint:

```
create table dbo.Workflow (
    ProjectId int not null,
    UserId int not null,
    primary key (UserId, ProjectId)
    foreign key (ProjectId) references dbo.Project (Id),
    foreign key (UserId) references dbo.[User] (Id),
);
```

And yes, constraints should be uniquely named, it will make schema comparisons and updates much easier.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply.. Yes foreign keys do not make uniqueness i do need it for referential integrity only. Fine i will change those into unique keys

Comment: The answer is mostly correct, but there is one error, which newcomers make with **Associative Tables**.  Here the `id` field and index is totally superfluous, it serves no purpose.  The notion that it is a PK is the result of stamping every file with an `id` field, and declaring it "PK", which is dead wrong.  Drop the `id` field and index.  Then make `(UserId, ProjectId)` the Primary Key.  Because it is.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA, normally you would be right. Judging by the subject area, however, I decided that OP will most probably have some tables under this one. And because most people have issues understanding multiple column foreign keys, I decided to add surrogate PK. If my guess was correct, it will also solve "movement" issue (switching to another project / user), which otherwise would result in PK update and require `on update cascade`, which is usually undesirable. But yes, that's just a guess.

Comment: @Roger Wolf.  (New point, responding to yours, my previous points stand.) Well, if Workflow has child tables, and the FK is the Workflow PD of `id`, it will have **no integrity** whatsoever.  They need to have integrity with the `Workflow.ProjectId,` and `Workflow.UserId`, not with `Workflow.id.` That is precisely the reason the `Workflow` PK should be `(ProjectId,` and `Workflow.UserId.`

Comment: @PerformanceDBA, looks more like "Natural vs. Surrogate" debate. If you need these Ids in child tables - fine, propagate them further down the chain. Problem is, the whole approach starts smelling suspiciously when your primary keys are 5-6 columns wide (and I've seen even wider, but that was a consolidated warehouse). Not the most convenient structure to work with, and besides, they bloat tables way too much, which will kill performance in OLTP scenario.

Comment: @Roger Wolf. *Debate* I don't bother debating, the evidence speaks for itself. *Inconvenient* The data sublanguage cannot help but be cumbersome. It is 2015, most of us use IDEs, we don't code SQL manually.  *"Bloat"* It sounds like you are speaking from debates, and beliefs, not from actual experience. The units of measure are no longer millisecs and MB, they are microsecs and GB.  If the PK is 5,6,7 columns, then that is what it is. The fear is a psychological problem, not a technology problem.

Comment: @Roger Wolf. *OLTP* The polar opposite is true, the inserts are nicely spread, we obtain data distribution, no conflicts.  **An `ID` field guarantees coflicts** because every user inserts on the last page.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA, we probably live in parallel universes then, because designing databases and coding SQL is what I do for a living. A lot of other stuff, too, but anyway. Good luck having your nice spreads, and never mind page splits - apparently, they only exist in my world.

Comment: @Roger Wolf. *OLTP* (a) Ok, so why do you not know that **all users block** to insert on the last page of an ID non-key ? My notion of OLTP is evidently quite different, eg. **no users block** because the inserts  are distributed.  (b) Have you heard about how to reserve space in the nicely distributed pages via` FILLFACTOR, RESERVEPAGEGAP,` etc ? I don't suffer PageSplits in my world because I make space in the pages.

Comment: @Roger Wolf  (c) **"Bloat" is totally false**, because you need the 5-6 col index anyway, for **row uniqueness**, so the total Heap + Indices is the same either way.  The question is not *if the PK is 5-6 columns*, it is *which index is Clustered*. (d) It must be a good living, living with page splits and ignoring last-page-write conflicts.  Forget serialised Transactions, you create serialised Files !